# Polling in ES6 and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

What I'm doing: I'm trying to make a simple polling mechanism with ES6.

Optimally, it should refresh a partial on `index` page every 5 seconds.

It doesn't work. Logs write that the template was rendered, but nothing happens in browser.

**app/javascript/packs/polls.js.erb:**

```
var sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
var poll = (promiseFn, time) => promiseFn().then(
             sleep(time).then(() => poll(promiseFn, time)))

poll(() => new Promise(() => {
  fetch('/shows/refresh_results', {
  method: 'GET'

  })//.then(response => {
    // document.getElementById('top-shows-table-container').innerHTML = ("<%= j render partial: 'shows/top_shows_table' %>");
    // })
}), 5000)
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb:**

```
class ShowsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @shows = Shows::OrderedByAverageReviewsScoreQuery.new.call
  end

  def refresh_results
    @shows = Shows::OrderedByAverageReviewsScoreQuery.new.call

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

    # render :index # this one doesn't work either
  end
end
```

**app/views/shows/refresh_results.js.erb:**

```
$('#top-shows-table-container').html("<%= render 'top_shows_table' %>"); 
CommentPoller.poll();
```

According to logs, the last file gets called. But nothing happens to page in browser.

```
Started GET "/shows/refresh_results" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-05 03:06:06 +0300
Processing by ShowsController#refresh_results as */*
  Rendering shows/refresh_results.js.erb
  Rendered shows/refresh_results.js.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I also tried inserting .erb code directly into `.polls.js`, which didn't work either. It is currently commented out. If I do uncomment it, it will produce this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/polls.js.erb
Module build failed: Error: rails-erb-loader failed with code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/.../projects/leaderboard-challenge/node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js:125:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
```

Comment: I don't see the part in your js where you place the result of your polling into the document. Am I not seeing correctly? Sorry if I missed it.

Comment: I expected controller to render from refresh_results.js.erb.

Comment: Ok, I added that part anyway just in case.

Comment: It looks to me like you're mixing up server-side and client-side activities. Seems like your `refresh_results` action should return `html` and then your `poll` function should place that `html` into the document.